# vue js components overlap the first time the page is reloaded

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

[the following is an image on the website, the "why atlaz" component always overlaps the component above it when the website is first loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HPHY.png)

[and when i scroll down again the "why atlaz" component returns to normal to where it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzlMa.jpg)

I made this website using nuxtjs and using vuetifyjs design, and here is the code from the "why atlaz" component:

Code

```css
.row-card-slider {
  margin-top: -45.8% !important;
  /*background-color: red;*/
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1904px) {
  .row-card-slider {
    /*margin-top: -41% !important;*/
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<v-container id="why-atlaz" class="hidden-sm-and-down" style="background-color: #2A384C; padding-top: 130px; padding-bottom: 180px">
  <v-row justify="center">
    <v-col xs="12" sm="12" md="12" lg="12" xl="9">
      <v-row>
        <v-col xs="12" sm="12" md="7" lg="7" xl="7">
          <v-img :src="require('~/assets/images/why-atlaz/1.png')" max-height="555" />
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <v-row justify="end" class="row-card-slider">
        <v-col xs="12" sm="12" md="7" lg="7" xl="7">
          <v-card style="background-color: #F4E8CA; padding-top: 12%; padding-bottom: 12%">
            <v-carousel :show-arrows="true" hide-delimiter-background height="300">
              <v-carousel-item v-for="(slide, i) in slides" :key="i" class="pl-16 pr-16">
                <v-container>
                  <v-row class="mb-3">
                    <v-col cols="12">
                      <span style="font-size: 34px; line-height: 34px; font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif; color: #2A384C !important; padding-left: 15px">
                            Why Atlaz?
                          </span>
                    </v-col>
                  </v-row>
                  <v-row>
                    <v-col cols="12">
                      <span style="font-size: 24px; line-height: 24px; font-weight: bold; font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif; color: #2A384C !important; padding-left: 15px" class="text-decoration-underline mb-2">
                            {{ slide.title }}
                          </span>
                      <v-card-text style="font-family: 'Nunito', serif !important; font-size: 20px; color: #2A384C !important">
                        {{ slide.text }}
                      </v-card-text>
                    </v-col>
                  </v-row>
                </v-container>
              </v-carousel-item>
            </v-carousel>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</v-container>
</div>
```

:

how to fix the overlapping problem, I've tried various ways but still I don't know why, please help me :)